# NSRunLoop runMode does not always process dispatch_async

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nsrunloop, dispatch-async

I'm trying to get a better understanding of queues and how they work.  This snippet is to test their behaviour:

```
- (void)dispatchQueueTest
{
    NSLog( @"Begin test on %@ thread", [NSThread isMainThread] ? @"main" : @"other" );
    dispatch_semaphore_t s = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog( @"Signalling semaphore" );
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(s);
    });

    NSLog( @"Waiting for worker" );
    while( dispatch_semaphore_wait( s, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW ) ) {
        NSDate* timeout = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10.f];
        // Process events on the run loop
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:timeout];
    }
    dispatch_release(s);
    NSLog( @"All sync'd up" );
}
```

As would be expected it produces this in the log:

```
Begin test on main thread
Waiting for worker
Signalling semaphore
All sync'd up
```

What is strange is that if this code is called from, say, - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated of a UIViewController, then it changes behaviour.  Specifically it deadlocks with the following log:

```
Begin test on main thread
Waiting for worker
```

My question is why does NSRunLoop runMode not process the block sent via dispatch_async in this situation but it does in others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a project where I push a `PlayerNameEntryViewController` onto a navigation controller.  I put a breakpoint in `-[PlayerNameEntryViewController viewDidAppear:]`.  Here's the stack trace when the breakpoint was hit:

```
#0  0x0002d3d3 in -[PlayerNameEntryViewController viewDidAppear:] at /Volumes/b/Users/mayoff/t/hotseat2/hotseat2/Home/PlayerNameEntryViewController.m:39
#1  0x00638fbf in -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] ()
#2  0x006392d4 in -[UIViewController __viewDidAppear:] ()
#3  0x006395d7 in -[UIViewController _endAppearanceTransition:] ()
#4  0x00648666 in -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:] ()
#5  0x007ee90e in -[UINavigationTransitionView _notifyDelegateTransitionDidStopWithContext:] ()
#6  0x007eec17 in -[UINavigationTransitionView _cleanupTransition] ()
#7  0x007eec86 in -[UINavigationTransitionView _navigationTransitionDidStop] ()
#8  0x005a2499 in -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] ()
#9  0x005a2584 in -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] ()
#10 0x00497e00 in CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) ()
#11 0x02e86515 in _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF ()
#12 0x015fe833 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#13 0x015fddb4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#14 0x015fdccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#15 0x01acd879 in GSEventRunModal ()
#16 0x01acd93e in GSEventRun ()
#17 0x00571a9b in UIApplicationMain ()
#18 0x00002461 in main at /Volumes/b/Users/mayoff/t/hotseat2/hotseat2/main.m:17
```

Notice frame #11.  It's a call to `_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF`.  That is the function that runs blocks put on the main queue.  So `viewDidAppear:` was actually called from inside a block that was added to the main queue with `dispatch_async`.

The main queue is a serial queue.  The definition of a serial queue is a queue that only executes one block at a time.  If the queue is executing a block, no other block on that queue can start.  So when you run the main run loop recursively, the run loop sees that it's already inside a block running on the main queue and doesn't try to start more blocks.  That's why your semaphore-signaling block never runs and your app hangs.

Note that sometimes `viewDidAppear:` is called from inside a queued block, and sometimes it's not.  You shouldn't rely on either behavior.

Comment: That explains a lot.  I was under the (mistaken) impression that the main thread and main queue had a 1-to-1 relationship.  But now I see I can run code on the main thread without going through the queueing mechanism of the main queue.  Thanks, Rob.

Comment: So a possible solution is to invoke `dispatchQueueTest` (or the signaling block) using `performSelectorOnMainThread:` instead of  `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()...`.

Comment: You might find it easier to switch to `CFRunLoopPerformBlock`.